# Stop excel plotting blank cells

Tags: excel

I currently have this code:

```
=IFERROR(IF(EDATE(A2,1)>TODAY(),"",EDATE(A2,1)),"")
```

However even though in some cases the cell is blank, it is still plotted on my graph. Apparently this is a know issue and I should use #N/A or NA() but neither or my implementations work:

```
=IFERROR(IF(EDATE(A2,1)>TODAY(),#N/A,EDATE(A2,1)),#N/A)
```

or

```
=IFERROR(IF(EDATE(A2,1)>TODAY(),NA(),EDATE(A2,1)),NA())
```

They both still split out N/A text when I drag the formular down. Can anyone show me how this should be implemented please?

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite convinced what your end result should be but

you might want to put the #N/As in ""

or

to use =ISNA(cell address)

Give me a full circle example from what you have to what you want to get, so we can integrate it for you.

Comment: So i take it its the "" - a basic idea to follow is that unless you are using any of the 3: 1= Function (IF, SUM etc), 2=Adress (a1,c33) or 3=numbers - you should always quote it. Excel tries to interpret it as one of the 3 and it messes things up -in this caseyou simply want to use it as text it seems.